# How can I keep a menu open when navigating to another page?

Tags: javascript, class, menu, html-lists, dropdown

I'm using a js code for additional menu options on click, but how can I keep the "click menu" permanently open, say after one of its option has been clicked, so the user won't have to start over again once taken to the new page.

HTML:

```
 <div class="c3" id="topLeftNav">
                <ul class="secnav" id="secnav">                                 
                    <h6>Generelt</h6> 
                    <li class="current"><a href="#">Ordklasser</a>
                    <ul class="ternav">
                            <li><a href="substantiver.html">Substantiver</a></li>
                            <li><a href="verber.html">Verber</a></li>
                            <li><a href="adjektiver.html">Adjektiver</a></li>
                            <li><a href="numeralier.html">Numeralier</a></li>
                            <li><a href="interjektioner.html">Interjektioner</a></li>
                                    </ul>
```

And my JS:

```
 ///ternav/secnav  -- catch inner clicks (ternav) first and preventDefault.
    $('.ternav li a').click(function () {
        window.location = $(this).attr('href');
    });

    //secnav 
    $('li').click(function (event) {
        if ($(this).has('ul').length) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if ($(this).find('ul').css("display") == "none") {
                $(this).find('a').eq(0).addClass('current');
                $(this).find('ul').slideDown();
            }
            else {
                $(this).find('ul').slideUp();
                $(this).find('a').eq(0).removeClass('current');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: [Related questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=keep+menu+open+when+new+page+site:stackoverflow.com&rlz=1C1ZCEB_enUS850US850&sxsrf=ACYBGNQNvYXdpkJGvYmkUjyjAQ2fhK7NiA:1579636990825&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjB_9itvpXnAhWCGM0KHcVYA8UQrQIoBDAAegQIBRAQ&biw=1472&bih=762&dpr=1.25)

Comment: My solution ended up being creating a new "ternav" (named "ternav2") with the exact same css characteristics, but not featured in the javascript. That would leave it open and upon click it would still be affected by the previous javascript, although I'm not sure why.

Comment: Good deal. Please provide and accept an answer or delete the question if it's a duplicate. Thanks.